# Unique visitors in real time in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to get most recent unique visitors like in Piwik?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google analytics does have realtime reporting.  It will tell will tell you:

- How many active visitors there are on the site
- Top referrals for those visitors
- Top active pages for those visitors
- Top keywords for those visitors
- Top locations for those visitors

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Google analytics realtime screenshot]

There is no way to get a list of the recent visitors, only a summary of their activity.

Comment: Even using advance segments? If not then I would suggest buy the recently launched premium Google analytics for advance reporting.

Comment: Advanced segments are a way of viewing only a portion of your visitors at a time.  They are not real time.  Premimum Analytics doesn't list any additional realtime enhancments on their capabilities page: http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/capabilities.html